# Timeout function still executes the operation

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, future

I am trying to create a method where user can change it's `firebase_authentication display name` with a **timeout** function attached to it:

```
Future<void> changeDisplayName({String name}) async {
    try {
      await _auth.currentUser
          .updateProfile(displayName: name)
          .timeout(Duration(seconds: 10))
          .then((value) => _createSnackbar(
              'Update Successfull', 'Your new display name is $name'));
    } on TimeoutException {
      Navigator.pop();
      _createSnackbar(
          'Timeout Exception', 'Operation stopped.');
    } catch (e) {
      _createSnackbar('Error Occurred', '${e.toString()}');
    }
  }
```

My intention is when the timeout exception is thrown, stop the operation entirely. But even the timeout exception is thrown the **`profile update`** is still done after the timeout. How can I avoid doing the operation when timeout is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to cancel the `updateProfile` operation. Once you make the method call, you will have to wait for it to complete and call `then` or `catch` to determines its result.

If you're trying to handle the case where the user's is not on a network, you may want to detect that condition before calling the API. But personally I'd consider just signaling the actual condition to the user instead: "This is taking longer than expected, you might want to try again later."

Comment: Oh then this approach is enough. Is this also the case for other Firebase operations such `updatePassword` || `reauthenticateWithCredential` ||  `updateEmail` ? Thanks for the clarification.